# How to solve The condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

When I type these code ,

```
z<-NULL
for(i in unique(A$KCL_ID)){
  RESULT<-A[A$KCL_ID==i,]
    if(RESULT$DAYS==min(RESULT$DAYS)){
      RESULT$DATE<-"closest"
    }else{RESULT$DATE<-RESULT$BMIextraction}
z<-rbind(z,RESULT)
  }
```

I get some error message like this:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (RESULT$DAYS == min(RESULT$DAYS)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (RESULT$DAYS == min(RESULT$DAYS)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (RESULT$DAYS == min(RESULT$DAYS)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (RESULT$DAYS == min(RESULT$DAYS)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How can I resolve this question?

Comment: `if` expects a logical scalar; perhaps you're looking for vectorised `ifelse`?

Comment: Reading `help("if")` should help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do an operation by group. The `ave()` function is helpful for this, although it's name might not seem obvious. First, use `ave()` to process rows by group

```
closest <- ave(A$DAYS, A$KLS_ID, FUN = function(x) x == min(x))
```

This splits `DAYS` into vectors defined by `KLS_ID`, then applies `FUN` to each vector. `closest` is a logical vector with value `TRUE` when the corresponding element is the minimum `DAYS` for all rows with the same `KSL_ID`. Then create a new column `A$DATE` with default value, and update the relevant entries

```
A$DATE = A$BMIextraction
A$DATE[closest] <- "closest"
```

There are two problems in your original code.

There appear to be 'ties', so several days are 'closest'. If you want to avoid these, update the function `x == min(x)` to resolve ties as you see fit, e.g., selecting the first row labelled 'closest' `x == min(x) & !duplicated(x == min(x))`.

The `DATE` or `BMIextraction` column appears to be a date, and you're trying to update with 'date' `"closest"`; obviously "closest" can't be represented as a date like `"06-04-2018"`. It is probably better to simply create a column containing a logical vector indicating that the member is the closest, i.e.,

```
A$closest <- ave(A$DAYS, A$KLS_ID, FUN = function(x) x == min(x))
```

Comment: @RichScriven Yes, updated.